# Custom combobox control for PropertyGrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox

I need some help creating a custom combobox editor for a property grid. The itemsource of the combobox is changing dynamically if a database connection is changed. The main problem is that I don't know how to access the selected item.
I tried to do this with a `SelectionChanged` event and it worked. But after I selected an item, the itemsource didn't change anymore if the database connection got changed. 
I'm thankful for any help and information also if someone has another idea of how I can do this.

The editor is called `SingleSelectEditor` and is used within the property grid like this:

```
Private _idNameList As ObservableCollection(Of String) = New ObservableCollection(Of String)
    <Category("2. ID Settings"), PropertyOrder(0)>
    <Editor(GetType(SingleSelectEditor), GetType(SingleSelectEditor))>
    Public Property IdNameList As ObservableCollection(Of String)
        Get
            Return _idNameList
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of String))
            _idNameList = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Now the user control looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SingleSelectEditor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="26" d:DesignWidth="200">
<Grid >
    <ComboBox Name="SingleSelectComboBox"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedString}" >
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Path="TestList"  Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

The code behind looks like this:

```
Public Class SingleSelectEditor
    Implements ITypeEditor

    Public Shared ReadOnly ValueProperty As DependencyProperty = _
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", GetType(ObservableCollection(Of String)), _
        GetType(SingleSelectEditor), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault))

    Public Property Value() As ObservableCollection(Of String)
        Get
            Return DirectCast(GetValue(ValueProperty), ObservableCollection(Of String))
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of String))
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Function ResolveEditor(ByVal propertyItem As PropertyItem) As FrameworkElement Implements ITypeEditor.ResolveEditor
        Dim binding = New Binding("Value")

        binding.Source = propertyItem
        binding.Mode = If(propertyItem.IsReadOnly, BindingMode.OneWay, BindingMode.TwoWay)

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(Me, ValueProperty, binding)

        Dim sSEVM As SingleSelectViewModel = New SingleSelectViewModel(Value)
        SingleSelectComboBox.DataContext = sSEVM

        Return Me
    End Function
End Class
```

And at least the ViewModel looks like this:

```
Public Class SingleSelectViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase

    Private _testList As ObservableCollection(Of String) = New ObservableCollection(Of String)

    Public Property TestList As ObservableCollection(Of String)
        Get
            Return _testList
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of String))
            _testList = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _selectedString As String

    Public Property SelectedString As String
        Get
            Return _selectedString
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _selectedString = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal tList As ObservableCollection(Of String))
        TestList = tList
    End Sub
End Class
```